# Problem with the K&R - Learning C - Arrays - ASCII

Tags: c, arrays

I'm currently learning C from The C Programming Language by Brian W Kernighan and Dennis M. Ritchie. I've gotten to the arrays section, and ran into a problem. When arrays are discussed in this book, they use this program:

```
`#include <stdio.h>
/* This program count digits, white space, others */
main()
{
int c, i, nwhite, nother;
int ndigit[10];
nwhite = nother = 0;
for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    ndigit[i] = 0;
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF){
    if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
        ++ndigit[c-'0'];
    else if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t')
        ++nwhite;
    else
        ++nother;
    printf("digits =");
    for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        printf(" %d", ndigit[i]);
    printf(", white space = %d, other = %d\n",
        nwhite, nother);}
}`
```

My question is: why the `-'0'` in `++ndigit[c-'0'];`? What does it mean? I noticed when I get rid of it, the program will not function properly. Edit: I heard it has something to do with ASCII. I have no idea what that is.

Comment: What did you find when you googled "ASCII"?

Comment: you mean -"0"? this is because the *character* zero is not the *number* zero.

Comment: If the digit characters are `'0'` to `'9'` then each one's numeric value is its character value - `'0'`. Can you see that `'0' - '0' == 0` and that `'1' - '0' == 1` and so on? The C standard guarantees that the digit charaters are encoded consecutively, but that has nothing to do with ASCII, which is just one set of character representations. There is no ASCII involved in the conversion from a character to a number in what I showed.

Comment: Take a look at the [ASCII table](https://www.asciitable.com/). The ASCII code for the character `'0'` is 48 and the ASCII code for the character `'9'` is 57. You could simply write 48 or 57 into the program instead of `'0'` and `'9'`, but it is better to do the latter because the meaning is clearer.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel worse than that, using `48` etc isn't portable. You've brought it back to ASCII which is irrelevant here, although it does help to explain it. The character encoding of the digit value `0` is `'0'`.

Answer (score 0):

If `c` is between `'0'` and `'9'`, due to c standard `'0'` to `'9'` are encoded consecutively, `c-'0'` will give out the numerical result of `c`. Say `c` is `'6'`, then `c-'0'==6`.